# python fabric run command return error as stdout

Tags: python, linux, awk, fabric

I use fabric run to execute command on another host, and i want to catch the stderr of executing command.
Fabric code like this:

```
def remoteTask(logfile):
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        result = run("tail -n4 %s | grep \'[error]\' | awk \'{print $1,$2,$0}\'" % logfile)
    if result.failed:
        raise Exception("Tail failed")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(result)
```

When the tail failed, the result.failed is false, and the value of result is stderr of tail. And the fabric won't throw an exception.

```
$ python exec.py
stdout: tail: cannot open `/var/log/test.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I just want to get a aborting or warning from fabric to know my script fails or not, but in this situation, i can't catch.

Comment: Please make sure to include your code in the question body and not just via screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing the question body for me. And I will make my question more clear next time! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way piping and paramiko works, fabric only returns the result code of the last command in a piped chain.  In this case, the `awk` command is returning 0 (or success==`True`).  You can work around this with other fabric constructs if you’d like:

```
from fabric.contrib import files
def remoteTask(logfile):
    if not files.exists(logfile):
        raise Exception('%s does not exist!' % logfile)
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        result = run("tail -n4 %s | grep \'[error]\' | awk \'{print $1,$2,$0}\'" % logfile)
```

---

For more on why this works this way you can read more about pipelines here:  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html

You can alo just run the command that you have with

```
set -o pipefail
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helps me a lot!